# SSH to Aws Ec2 instances without Public, Private Keys and Public Ips

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, elastic-ip

In my company one of the coworker created Ec2 instance without public IP address. I don't have public and private keys. i can make connection with SSM Manager or EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint but i wanna make connection with my local. How can i do that ?

i need to ssh in our private ec2 instance without pub/private keys.

Comment: You can't do that without the private key. And even if you had the private key, you can't connect to it from your local computer since it doesn't have a public IP address. SSM Session Manager is really more secure than SSH, especially since it allows you to keep the EC2 instance from exposing port 22 on the Internet. Is there a reason the `aws ssm start-session` command isn't good enough?

Answer (score 1):

Your instance doesn't have a public IP. You don't have a key-pair for the instance. These are 2 reasons why you can't connect to that instance via ssh.

Still, you can connect to your instance from your local machine. You already mentioned that you can use SSM. So, to connect from your local machine, you can use `AWS CLI` with `Session Manager plugin`. This way, you don't need to add public IP to your instance, don't need to open ssh port and no need to juggle with ssh keys.

Here are instructions on how to [install the plugin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html), depending on your operating system.

Obviously, like for AWS CLI regular usage, you need `access key` and `secret access key`.

With `Session Manager plugin`, you can also use [port forwarding](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-sessions-start.html#sessions-start-port-forwarding) which I assume was the main reason you were actually looking to have ssh access from local machine.